# Make user script own code that interacts with own application using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm building an application where you can create and draw graphs and trees using C# and .NET. Additionally, you can display some properties of that graph such as the number of components or number of circles etc.

Besides the own methods I put into the application, I want to give the user the possibility to write their own code that calculates their own properties of the graph, maybe for example the shortest path or stuff like this. Then I want those properties to be implemented in the application and to be displayed and properly calculated just like my own properties.

Which language the user can use doesn't matter for now, though JavaScript would be ideal.

Is there any way to do that? Maybe there are frameworks that interpret that language at the same time and transfer the calculated data to my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Roslyn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/) to the rescue! Microsoft has a great API to access compiler services on the fly. Here's a [tutorial](https://mikecodes.net/2020/05/11/in-app-scripts-with-c-roslyn/) for providing in-app c# scripting. As a word of caution, if this is anything beyond a toy, I highly suggest you research the security implications inherent in parsing untrusted code and find some way to containerize this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think that helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Stack languages are fairly efficient -- witness the underlying intermediate language of .NET or the JVM. So I use Forth as my embedded scripting language because I can write it myself, and keep it as small or simple as I like. Recommend making examples happen in your local c#, then working backwards in tiny steps, until it's scriptable. A few paths through, then start filling in.

Answer (score 0):

Given the roslyn usage site sub address changed you can use this :

https://mikecodes.net/blog/in-app-scripts-with-c-roslyn